# Insertion Sort Average Case

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, average, sorting

Although I know "Insertion Sort" has an average time complexity of O(n^2) (although not really familiar with the notation myself, i got that O(f(n)) is basically any constant multiplied to f(n) or added to it, and when f(n) is polynomial you can also add lower degree terms - lines are blurred when talking about n*log_2(n) and adding n, is that still O(n*log_2 (n))?) and came up with a more-or-less heuristic argument for it, I want to calculate the exact implementation time of the following algorithm, specified in pseudo-code:

[image]

We will count as a single step any arithmetic operation: adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, modulo(n) and we will count assignments and comparisons and bitwise and Boolean operations as a single step as well.

The reason I am bringing this up is because I want to get the feeling that Computer Science can indeed work within the exact. Also it's because I have some ideas as to one might go about a problem like this: I was thinking that we would get a sort of distribution function over the n! different cases and then aproximate the points in the plane with a function (although this would be no longer exact..) and calculate the mean value of the function chosen. Since we have so many cases studying them separately would be impossible. I was thinking that group theory equivalence classes might solve the issue. It would be awesome if the proof involved both high level calculus and high level algebra.

Comment: Is this question not getting attention because of all the text? Is it glitched?

Comment: Can anyone provide a hint

Comment: Can anyone at least point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: Is anything wrong with the question itself? I'm not used to this kind of behaviour on mathematics stack exchange, usually people downgrade you or like the question, anyway, some sort of activity. Being ignored is such a shame.

Comment: Possible computer bug: It looks like the last entry in the $A$ vector is untouched and unshifted.  Should the above algorithm be changed to start as:  "for each $i \in \{2, ..., length(A)\}$?

Comment: In this problem (with possible bug fixed), I think at each step $i \in \{2, ..., length(A)\}$ the algorithm takes the $i$th entry of the $A$ vector and places it into an already-sorted list of all $(i-1)$ entries that came before.  It seems that average complexity is only a factor of 2 better than worst-case complexity. So both have complexity $O(n^2)$. Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, it should, although if we change that, we need to change the condition for the index "j" as well, to have it bigger than 1. The pseudo-code is referencing C, a language that keeps the first instance of an array, for example A here, as of index 0. So A[0] is our first element.

Comment: I see:  So in the pseudo-code the entries are indexed $i \in \{1, ..., length(A)\}$ but in C the indexes are shifted to $i \in \{0, .., length(A)-1\}$.  In that case perhaps there is no computer bug in that program.  Then, can you specify the precise qeuestion you have?  Your question kind of went on a tangent about $O(n)$ notation and so on...

Comment: I am expecting a rather more exact approach, that's why I have asked the question on the mathematics website. I already know the big-O notation complexity and I can prove to myself that it is true. What I don't know are the exact constants, the constants computer scientists aren't quite interested in. But I get satisfied only with a hint, a direction that could lead me to find those exact constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let vector $A$ have length $n$. For simplicity, let's use the entry indexing $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.

At each step $i \in \{2, ..., n\}$: The $A$ vector is assumed to be already sorted in its first $(i-1)$ components. So we compare $A(i)$ to each of its previous components and insert it once we find the first component that is less than $A(i)$.  Let $K_i$ be the (random) number of comparisons we make on step $i$, where $K_i \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$. Then:

$$ \mbox{Total number of comparisons}  = \sum_{i=2}^n K_i $$

#### Worst case complexity:

Suppose the original $A$ vector was arranged in *reverse order*, for example, if $A = (4.5, 3.2, 1.0, 0.9)$.  Let $K_i^{worst}$ denote the value of $K_i$ under this "worst-case" arrangement. Then $K_i^{worst}=i-1$ for all $i$, which is the largest possible value it could take for each $i \in \{2, ..., n\}$.  Hence: 
$$ \mbox{Worst case number of comparisons} = \sum_{i=2}^n K_i^{worst} = \sum_{i=2}^n(i-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

#### Average case complexity:

At each step $i$, if we assume that entry $A(i)$ has a value that is equally likely to lie in one of the $i$ positions defined by the previous $i-1$ sorted entries, then we can easily get a probability mass function for $K_i$, namely, we can compute $P[K_i=k]$ for $k \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$.  You can calculate that (be careful with the end case $P[K_i=i-1]$) and then you can easily calculate $E[K_i]$, and so: 
$$ E[\mbox{Number of comparisons}] = \sum_{i=2}^n E[K_i] $$
As a sanity check, you know this expected complexity should be less than the worst case.

---

PS:  We say that a sequence of nonnegative numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is $O(n^2)$ if there is a real number $c\geq 0$ such that: 
$$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^2} \leq c $$
Equivalently, $a_n$ is $O(n^2)$ if there is a constant $d \geq 0$ such that $a_n \leq dn^2$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

We say $a_n$ is $O(\log(n))$ if there is a constant $d$ such that $a_n \leq d\log(n)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Isn't E (k) = k/2 ?

Comment: It is "almost true" that $E[K_i]=i/2$. In fact it is slightly more when $i>2$, and the exact value can be computed by specifying the mass function $P[K_i=k]$ for $k \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining complexity for me, that makes sense.

Comment: I don't really understand how it doesn't exactly half the number. But i guess it's because I'm not familiar with statistics that much

Comment: Can you compute $P[K_i=i-1]$? Or $P[K_i=1]$? [Note that there are $i$ positions for $A(i)$ to be in relative to the previous $i-1$ entries, but there are only $i-1$ entries to check.]

Comment: Is it something like Monty Hall, in the sense that whenever I do one more comparison, the probability re-normalizes across all the rest presumable comparisons?

Comment: No.  $E[K_i] = \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} kP[K_i=k]$.  The exact value is found by determining $P[K_i=k]$ for all $k \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$. And since there are $i$ possible (equally likely) positions for $A(i)$ to be in relative to its previous $(i-1)$ sorted entries, but only $i-1$ previous entries that can be checked, there must be two positions that correspond to the same required amount of checking. So $P[K_i=k]$ is _not_ the same for all $k \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$.

Comment: OOO I think I see now.

Comment: Whether the element is in the second or the first position after the whole process has the same amount of computational steps, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the only difference.  So $P[K_i=k]$ is "almost constant" over $k \in \{1, ..., i-1\}$, but not quite.

Comment: That's cool, thanks for the patience.